# babylonjs react typescript question/advise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babylonjs

Could you please guide me with the following : I am trying to convert the babylonjs - react class component to one using hooks (created with the CRA template). The page that I am referring to is : - https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/babylonjs_and_reactjs

### 1) first question :

for the line :

```
export default class Scene extends React.Component<SceneProps & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>, {}> {

  private scene: BABYLON.Scene;
  private engine: BABYLON.Engine;
  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
```

---

What is the equivalent React Functional Component ? (not sure what to do of the types in the angle brackets :-

```
const Scene : React.FC <> = () => {
```

---

2) The private variables should I make the useState ?

Looking at the link https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/babylonjs_and_reactjs; could we please advise be what the typescript equivalent code look like; I tried it with the CRA template; cannot get the appropriate types to pass

Answer (score 1):

1. First Question

```
const Scene: React.FC<
  SceneProps & 
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>
> = props => {

  // Don't worry, they are private (equivalent)
  // i.e. their scope is within this function
  // Fun Fact: JavaScript doesn't have `private`
  // and typescript can enforce it only within it's compiler  
  // Because, JS was built as a functional programming language

  // let scene: BABYLON.Scene;
  // let engine: BABYLON.Engine;
  // let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

  // There's one problem in declaring variables
  // Directly like this,
  // These variables gets created or updated for 
  // Every update i.e. every function call. So, use this

  const scene = React.useRef<BABYLON.Scene>(null);
  const engine: React.useRef<BABYLON.Engine>(null);
  const canvas: React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);


  // and access them using .current
  const bar = scene.current.bar;
  // Or reassign the same way
  scene.current = foo
```

2. Second Question

```
  // As I have said in the previous comment,
  // The scope of this variable is within this function
  // So it's equivalent of being private variable
  const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
```

Comment: Many thanks, I am now able to convert it to Functional Components correctly; I am getting this warning ; because I am setting the engine variable in the useEffect hook  (doesnt seem to affect anything .. but I hate to see the warnings on the console): please advise if this is critical:-

Comment: Line 55:18:  Assignments to the 'engine' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps